# Kafka Error reading field 'correlation_id': java.nio.BufferUnderflowException

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Getting this kafka exception on consumer :

```
org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.types.SchemaException: Error reading field 'correlation_id': java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
at org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.types.Schema.read(Schema.java:71)
at org.apache.kafka.common.requests.ResponseHeader.parse(ResponseHeader.java:53)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.handleCompletedReceives(NetworkClient.java:435)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:265)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.clientPoll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:320)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:213)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:193)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.awaitMetadataUpdate(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:134)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureCoordinatorKnown(AbstractCoordinator.java:184)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:886)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:853)
```

No client-server version mismatch.

Answer (score 3):

> Be sure your client connect to a real Kafka port !

this specific error happens while parsing (one of?) the first **header field** of the expected kafka message, as shown by the invocation of **ResponseHeader.java** in stack-trace.

So this can occurs if you target a listening port that has nothing to do with kafka server.

> just a 1 minute check !

Otherwise, you should check for a client-server version mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I was having trouble with unit test failure with above exception. When I inspected the port(9092) being used on local machine, it was bound to already running process, worth checking if there is process for Kafka running locally. If you are sure you are not expecting it to be running, kill it by finding its pid. (Don't try on production though :P )

```
lsof -i:9092
kill -9 <PID_FROM_ABOVE_IF_ANY>
```